# CSRF-TOKEN Issues while parsing the GET Request

Tags: csrf, csrf-token

While parsing the GET Request HTTP call I received a 400 Bad Request Error and if I checked the request data, I could see some errors under the cookie header CSRF-TOKEN.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl5Im.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl5Im.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWrvr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWrvr.png)

I have tried with the new token, like I have repeated the action in the UI then Copied the latest token, and then used it but it didn't work